# Quarkus `@ServerExceptionMapper`: unwrap and forward to next exception mapper

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy

I have some HTTP endpoints that end up throwing `WebApplicationException`s. Those get mapped using a global exception mapper:

```
@ServerExceptionMapper
public Response unwrapWebApplicationException(WebApplicationException exception) {
    return Response
            .status(exception.getResponse().getStatus())
            .entity("Bla bla something happened, technical details: " + exception.getResponse().getEntity())
            .build();
}
```

Now, in some circumstances my `WebApplicationException` is wrapped in some other exception, for example a `ArcUndeclaredThrowableException`. A constructed example may look like this:

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        WebApplicationException webApplicationException = new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.CONFLICT);
        throw new ArcUndeclaredThrowableException(webApplicationException);
    }
}
```

My goal is to write an exception mapper that unwraps the `ArcUndeclaredThrowableException`, but instead of directly returning a result, hands the inner exception to the next exception mapper, if one exists.

I found that this can be done using [`jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers#getExceptionMapper(Class<T> type)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/ext/providers#getExceptionMapper(java.lang.Class)). I wrote the following utility:

```
/**
 * Attempts to unwrap the exception's cause (shallowly, not recursively) and invoke that exception's exception mapper instead.
 * If the exception has no cause, it is thrown as-is. If it has a cause but the cause has no exception mapper, the cause exception is thrown as-is.
 */
private static <T extends Throwable> Response unwrapCause(T exception, Providers providers) throws Throwable {
    var cause = exception.getCause();
    if (cause == null) {
        throw exception;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<Throwable> exceptionClass = (Class<Throwable>) cause.getClass();
    ExceptionMapper<Throwable> exceptionMapper = providers.getExceptionMapper(exceptionClass);
    if (exceptionMapper == null) {
        throw cause;
    }
    return exceptionMapper.toResponse(cause);
}
```

Now in theory all I need is to declare my exception mapper and call `unwrapCause()` in it. However, I was unable to obtain a proper instance of `Providers`. The [Quarkus documentation on REST](https://quarkus.io/version/main/guides/rest#exception-mapping) states:

> Your exception mapper may declare any of the following parameter types: [...] Any of the [Context objects](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#context-objects).

And within those context objects, `Providers` is listed. However, when I try this:

```
/**
 * If quarkus encounters a checked exception in some proxy code that bubbles up to some other code that does not declare that checked exception,
 * it needs to wrap the exception in a runtime exception for it to be valid Java. Quarkus uses the {@link ArcUndeclaredThrowableException} for this.
 * It is of no informational value, so let's just always unwrap it.
 */
@ServerExceptionMapper
public Response unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions(ArcUndeclaredThrowableException exception, Providers providers) throws Throwable {
    return unwrapCause(exception, providers);
}
```

I get this error during a Quarkus build:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parameter 'providers' of method 'unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions of class 'org.acme.ExceptionMappers' is not allowed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.processor.generation.exceptionmappers.ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.getTargetMethodParamsInfo(ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.java:607)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.processor.generation.exceptionmappers.ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.generateRRResponse(ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.java:478)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.processor.generation.exceptionmappers.ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.generateGlobalMapper(ServerExceptionMapperGenerator.java:313)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.deployment.ResteasyReactiveScanningProcessor.handleCustomAnnotatedMethods(ResteasyReactiveScanningProcessor.java:410)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

If I instead try to inject a `Providers` instance outside like this:

```
@Context
Providers providers;

/**
 * If quarkus encounters a checked exception in some proxy code that bubbles up to some other code that does not declare that checked exception,
 * it needs to wrap the exception in a runtime exception for it to be valid Java. Quarkus uses the {@link ArcUndeclaredThrowableException} for this.
 * It is of no informational value, so let's just always unwrap it.
 */
@ServerExceptionMapper
public Response unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions(ArcUndeclaredThrowableException exception) throws Throwable {
    return unwrapCause(exception, providers);
}
```

I end up with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should never be called
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers$GeneratedExceptionHandlerFor$WebApplicationException$OfMethod$unwrapWebApplicationException.toResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers$GeneratedExceptionHandlerFor$WebApplicationException$OfMethod$unwrapWebApplicationException.toResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers.unwrapCause(ExceptionMappers.java:49)
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers.unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions(ExceptionMappers.java:32)
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers$GeneratedExceptionHandlerFor$ArcUndeclaredThrowableException$OfMethod$unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions.toResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.acme.ExceptionMappers$GeneratedExceptionHandlerFor$ArcUndeclaredThrowableException$OfMethod$unwrapArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions.toResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.RuntimeExceptionMapper.mapException(RuntimeExceptionMapper.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ResteasyReactiveRequestContext.mapExceptionIfPresent(ResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:15)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:599)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

How can I write an exception mapper that just unwraps a certain exception, having the cause go through any other potentially defined exception mappers?

Comment: You should be able to use a `jakarta.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<ArcUndeclaredThrowableException>` then just annotate it with `@Provider`. That would be the Jakarta REST way at least.

Comment: Can you provide an example as an answer? Last I tried whether I implement the exception mappers using `@ServerExceptionMapper` or `ExceptionMapper<ArcUndeclaredThrowableException>` made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the unwrapping of the exception at all, Quarkus handles that for you (if the original exception is not being handled).

So all you have to write is:

```
@ServerExceptionMapper
public Response unwrapWebApplicationException(WebApplicationException exception) {
    return Response
            .status(exception.getResponse().getStatus())
            .entity("Bla bla something happened, technical details: " + exception.getResponse().getEntity())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Though this seems to be a special case for `ArcUndeclaredThrowableException`s in particular, correct? If I wanted to unwrap e.g. a `RollbackException`, I'd need to follow your original answer (before the edits)?

Comment: `RollbackException` is also in the same special case category :)

Comment: Oh wow, that's perfect, thank you! Turns out why it didn't work for me was because there's another exception mapper on `Throwable` that ends up handling the `ArcUndeclaredThrowableExceptions`, bypassing the automatic unwrapping.

Comment: Right, that's a typical problem with a exception mappers

Comment: I've tried to work around this by removing the exception mapper and use a server response filter instead, but that also doesn't work since the response filter does not get invoked for 500 server errors. Do you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78233287/add-serverresponsefilter-for-500-server-errors ?