# Add custom data to 500 server errors responses

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy

I am trying to modify the responses returned in case of uncontrolled errors (status code >= 500), in this case I want to add a correlation ID to the response for easier error log aggregation in a distributed application. For status codes <= 499 this works fine with `@ServerResponseFilter`

```
@ServerResponseFilter
public void modifyResponse(ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
    Log.debugf("Calling modifyResponse with context %s", responseContext);
    if (responseContext.getStatus() >= 400) {
        if (responseContext.getEntity() instanceof String) {
            responseContext.setEntity("Error with Correlation-ID " + MDC.get("correlation_id") + ": " + responseContext.getEntity());
        }
    }
}
```

However, `modifyResponse` is not invoked for responses with status codes >= 500, even when thrown "manually" using e.g. `throw new WebApplicationException("abort!", 500)`.

Is there a way I can enrich the HTTP response with some custom data in case of 500 server errors?

Comment: No. You’re not supposed to include any data with a 5xx response. That’s what it’s for. To conceal.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an exceptionmapper to catch and decorate the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually the expected behavior.

If a thrown exception is **not** handled by an exception mapper, then no response filters are run.